# Change cursor to pointer on hover right side of td

Tags: html-table, cursor

I have a table with td's. I would like it so that the user sees the cursor change into a pointer when he/she reaches **the right border** of the specific td, and revert back to the normal pointer when the user is not hovering the right border.

Googled a lot but I cannot seem to find an answer. There's hope someone here can help me...?

I would like it to be pure CSS, but maybe there is need for some query too?

Comment: Ok, thankfully Varnit put me on the right track! I'll post the code that eventually worked for me in safari, in the hopes that I may help others.

Comment: var threshold = 20;   

$( $Table + ' td' ).mousemove(function(e){

        if( ( ( $(this).innerWidth() - e.offsetX ) < threshold ) ) {
              $('html,body').css('cursor','pointer')
        }
        else
        {
              $('html,body').css('cursor','auto')
        }

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use CSS to modify the behavior of the type of cursor in your case you can use

```
your_td_tag:hover { 
    cursor:progress
}
```

If you specifically want to select border only you have to use some javascript hacky stuff

```
$('div').click(function(e){
    if(  e.offsetX <= parseInt($(this).css('borderLeftWidth'))){
       $("div").css("cursor:progress");
    }
});
```

here div can be replaced by any tag and cursor-progress can be replaced by your desired cursor.

there are various types of cursors available by default
auto
crosshair
default
e-resize
grab
help
move
n-resize
ne-resize
nw-resize
pointer
progress
s-resize
se-resize
sw-resize
text
w-resize
wait
not-allowed
no-drop

you can also use your custom cursor as follows

```
your_td_tag_selector:hover{
cursor: url('some-cursor.ico'), default;
}
```

the default here is used as a fallback mechanism so if some-cursor.ico is not supported or not available it will fall back to default cursor.

let me know if it solves your problem..

Comment: thanks for responding! it does solve it partially, because I want the cursor to change when the user hovers over the right side of the td, nowhere else. and change back when he/she moves the cursor off of the right side of the td. Do you know of a way to do that?

Comment: still works partially I'm afraid to say :-(.   it doest change the cursor now, but on the left side (hey ill fix that np), the problem is though that It doesn't change back when I hover out.

Comment: use the following now:  $('td').hover(function(e){
     if(  e.offsetX <= parseInt($(this).css('borderLeftWidth'))){
     $('html,body').css('cursor','pointer')
     }
 });

Comment: no issues bro you have to include one more event to get it back to the default cursor

Comment: try to add $(td).mouseout() function

Comment: Thanks Varnit, you put me on the right track! I've used mouse move now in a combination with using the mouse's location in relation to the right border of that td. I've put my code in the opening question!

Comment: very happy to help you can you upvote the answer as well